# Eclipse not highlighting/jumping to row in debug view when suspending

Tags: eclipse, debugging, helios

Environment:
Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 (Build 20110218-0911)
glassfish 3.0-b39
Maven 2 (SVN)
JDK6
JSF2.0.0-PR
LOG4J 1.2.16

We are developing a webapp using above environment and we are encountering the following hassle when debugging:

First time debug after restart of Eclipse: breakpoint are recognised, suspended, and the corresponding line is jumped to and highlighted correctly.
After that, anytime we try to debug, the thread suspends correctly but the row is neither jumped to nor highlghted, so we need to expand/collapse through the threads to see where it suspended.

Cleaning project, Building (using Maven), Server restarts, refreshing and so on does not help. One always has to shut down eclipse and restart.

Any ideas on this? Many thanks!
Marc

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I have the same problem