# Eclipse debug mode not highlighting, jumping to row

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-indigo

I running Eclipse EE, Indigo Build id: 20110916-0149, with Subclipse installed.

My Eclipse does not properly debug. This has been an ongoing issue for some time, but I have managed so far. I tend to alternate between working heavily in Java and sql, so I first noticed the problem when returning to Java with no clear reason or cause to it. I have tried to remove the project, start with a clean eclipse and get the project again from the repository, but to no avail. Cleaning/rebuilding doesn't work, either.

When set to debug, if a breakpoint is hit Eclipse will prompt to enter debug mode as expected. The perspective will switch over, but the file with the breakpoint will not open, and if it is already open then the line will not be targeted and highlighted. In the Debug View, it lists the location of cursor during debug, such as "Daemon Thread [http-8080-Processor23] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 91 in CLASS))", so I know that the thread suspends correctly.  If I F6 (Step Over) I can see it going through the lines of code as expected, but nothing is highlighted or jumped to in the main window.

This project is a jsp-based web app. If I switch workspaces into a small single-class project that just does some read-write on some excel files, then debugging works as expected. The settings between the two workspaces are identical. At one point I even copied the working eclipse debug files over the ones in the broken workspace, to no avail. This at first led me to believe that the problem was with the project itself, but no one else is affected, nor are we able to replicate the problem.

I have found only [one previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106462/eclipse-not-highlighting-jumping-to-row-in-debug-view-when-suspending) that seems related to mine (though I dont even get the one debug after an eclipse restart), that went unanswered. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a resolution for the problem. I created a separate Eclipse folder and workspace to ensure a clean installation, and recorded my steps along the way. When the problem persisted in the same manner (working on generic project, not working on jsp-based one) I examined what was there that might influence this and ultimately discovered that a plugin given to me (Sysdeo Tomcat Launcher Plugin) was either broken or outdated (on 3.1.0). This was a folder plugin that adds a dropdown 'Tomcat' option to the File bar in Eclipse. This was added when I first installed eclipse, so since it worked for a while it never occurred that this may be the issue. I removed it and downloaded the latest version (3.3.0) which has fixed the problem. I can't account for it suddenly failing one day, but the problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the actual Debug button at the top.  I ran into this problem just now with only using the Tomcat start button.  With the actual bug button, I'm now able to see the highlighted lines.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Resolved it by closing Eclipse and running it again as Administrator. The green highlighter suddenly reappeared !

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened due to unavailability of source code in the **Tomcat's classpath**. So to overcome this problem you need to add the source code in the classpath under JVM settings of Tomcat through preference.

Please let me know whether it solves your problem in respective eclipse or not..